# how to achieve count(distinct) without group by in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I want to find the count(distinct column name) wihtout using group by in hive.
my input is :

```
name  id
a      2
a      3
a      4
b      1
c      4
c      4
d      7
d      9
```

my expected output is

```
name   count
a       3
b       1
c       1
d       2
```

can some tell me how to achieve this without using group by. please help

Comment: And what is the issue with `group by`?

Answer (score 2):

A canonical solution with no explicit `group by` is `select` distinct with window functions:

```
select distinct name, count(distinct id) over (partition by name)
from t;
```

In your case, I strongly recommend the `group by` version:

```
select name, count(distinct id)
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: `distinct` clause with a window function and `distinct` within a window function isn't supported in all Hive versions.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala . . . But it is supported by the more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery :

```
select distinct t.name,
       (select count(distinct id) from table t1 where t1.name = t.name) as count
from table t;
```

However, `GROUP BY` is really appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

just use `count` aggregate function with `distinct` keyword

```
select name,count(distinct id) as cnt from table
group by name
```